# languages right to left direction issue fig.write_image "jpg" plotly

Tags: python, plotly, export, jpeg

I have an issue to export chart to jpg in languages right to left direction (arbic -hebrew -urdu).
when I am using the command "plotly.offline.plot" to export to .html no issue and all brackets are ok.
but with command "fig.write_image" to export to image jpg the brackets are missed up.

The chart is sunburst

The HTML version:

[image: HTML]

The JPG version:

[image: jpg]

Data used are:

الأخ (الأقدم)

بھائی (سب سے پرانا)

אח (המבוגר ביותר)

is it an issue or there is some property to set.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the encoding on the parentheses is different than the other text.  Make sure everything is UTF-8 and see if that helps. You will likely have to make your question reproducible for someone to help with exactly what is wrong here.

Comment: How to set that in pd.read_excel, again to export to html no issue but to export  jpeg the text of data is not well organized

Comment: I suspect the issue is that the RTL text is being rendered within an LTR context. When the text is being rendered, the text direction should be identified. You might want to try wrapping a bidi envelope around the strings, i.e. add embedding or isolate characters to explicitly control text direction.

Comment: Is your plotly version up to date, and you have kaleido installed? If not, you may be using the legacy backend. Kaledio uses a headless chromium instance, so in theory it should have no trouble with RTL. I was intending to do a Sorani Kurdish example. So will post it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

`write_image()` renders RTL text within an LTR context, so mixed script strings or strings containing punctuation will not render correctly.

A hack to fix rendering involves wrapping the strings in bidirectional formatting characters. I use an internal module with this functionality, which wraps each string with the characters U+202B (RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING) and U+202C (POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING).

A Sorani Kurdish example:

https://github.com/enabling-languages/python-i18n/blob/main/notebooks/plotly2.ipynb

The strings exist within an LTR embedding, the formatting characters create an RTL embedding within the LTR embedding.

We use embedding formatting characters, rather than isolate formatting characters, since kaleido cannot correctly handle the isolate formatting characters.

Something like:

```py
def bidi_envelope(text, dir="rtl"):
    text = f"\u202A{text}\u202C" if dir.lower() =="ltr" else f"\u202B{text}\u202C"
    return text
```